# Postgresql how to show strings only with a certain number of occurrences of a character?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postgresql, I need to select only those names that contain 2 occurrences of the letter "e", not more not less.
Does anybody have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case sensitive:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  col LIKE '%e%e%';
AND    col NOT LIKE '%e%e%e%';
```

Or:

```
...
WHERE length(translate(col, 'e','')
    = length(col) - 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_replace` [function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html):

```
where regexp_replace('eexx', '[^e]', '', 'g') = 'ee'
```

This will replace anything except `e` with empty string. Than it is easy to test for `ee`.